# Template and Vector

Tags: templates, vector

IDE said that there are some errors on Student*

I don`t understand why.

I just want to make class Student under the template code

and print these classes on the screen

How can I clear these errors?

```
template <class T>
class Student
{
    T id; // int id;
    std::string name;
    T grade; // double grade;
public:
    template <class T>
    Student<T>::Student() //
    {
        std::string list[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J" };
        id = rand() % 10000 + 10000;
        name = list[rand() % 10] + list[rand() % 10] + list[rand() % 10];
        grade = rand() % 10 * 1.5 + 2;
    }
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, std::vector<Student*>::iterator it);
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, std::vector<Student*>::iterator it)
{
    stream << (*it)->id << "," << (*it)->name << "," << (*it)->grade;
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Student*> v;
    std::vector<Student*>::iterator it;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        v.push_back(new Student);
    }

    cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(std::ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    for (it=v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the errors thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Student is a template class. To use it you must specify a type argument. Namely, when you try to create a vector of Students, you have to say what kind of students:

`std::vector<Student<int>*> v`

or so. Bear in mind that a pointer to a Student can't point to every kind of Student instantiation - `Student<int>` and `Student<double>` are totally different types. Same goes to the creation of a new Student, which misses the type argument.

This actually makes me wonder why would you want the student class to be a template at all. In your comment, `id` and `grade` are said to have different types, even though they both use `T`. Why would you want those fields to be of parametric types?